# How to set an Image on Android Tabs to Occupy all spaces?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-drawable, android-tabs, tabwidget

How do you make a tab's background occupy all of that tab's space? Because it seems like a default padding is set on a tab.

What I am aiming for:

[image]

What happens:

[image]
[image]

Also, how do you remove that light under a tab? It's part of the API 14 right? So I should be able to manipulate it using custom styles?

Comment: Why don't you create a custom layout?

Comment: I wanted to use Android's Tab Layout. Is it faster if I cheated to look the layout like a Tab using custom layout with buttons instead?

Comment: It is not a good practice. Try adding styles.